# ui-router automatically routes to parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular app with ui router with a nested view (in the config method):

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        'mainView' : {
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        }
    },
    authenticate: true
})
.state('home.cargaDePadrones', {
    url: '/cargaDePadrones',
    views: {
        'contentView' : {
            templateUrl: 'templates/cargaDePadrones.html',
            controller: 'CargaDePadronesController'
        }
    },
    authenticate: true
})
```

In the home view I have this:

```
<md-content layout="row" layout-fill>
    <md-content ng-show="showTreeMenu" class="TextoInstitucional menuCell" flex="20">
        <treecontrol class="tree-classic" tree-model="treeData" options="treeOptions"
            on-selection="showSelected(node)" expanded-nodes="expandedNodes">
            {{node.name}}
        </treecontrol>
    </md-content>
    <div style="background-color: #CECECE; width: 9px;" layout="column" layout-align="center center">
        <a flex href="#" ng-show="showTreeMenu" ng-click="toggleMenu()">
            <img style="border: 0 none;" src="images/middle_toggle_left.gif" />
        </a>
        <a flex href="#" ng-show="!showTreeMenu" ng-click="$parent.toggleMenu()">
            <img style="border: 0 none;" src="images/middle_toggle_right.gif" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <md-content class="TextoGrande contentCell" style="padding-left: 10px;" ui-view="contentView" ng-cloak flex>
    </md-content>
</md-content>
```

and in the home controller I've got this:

```
$scope.showTreeMenu = true;

$scope.toggleMenu = function() {
    $scope.showTreeMenu = !$scope.showTreeMenu;
};
```

The idea is that whenever the user hits the anchor, a part of the page hides (the menu) to give it more space to work and when it hits the other anchor it bring the menu back.

The problem is that whenever I hit the anchor that is visible in the home view (executing the toggleMenu scope method) the content in the nested view (named 'contentView') dissapears. Looking at the browser path, it automatically routes from /home/cargaDeParones to /home (routing from the child state to the parent state). I'm assuming that this is happening because the toggleMenu method is defined in the Home controller, but I don't know how to prevent this behaviour.

How can I expose a parent's scope method without routing back to it??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchor tags href value is '#'
, that is the reason it is taking to the home page. Please change the anchor tags href tag to :

```
<a flex href="JavaScript:void(0)" ng-show="showTreeMenu" ng-click="toggleMenu()">
        <img style="border: 0 none;" src="images/middle_toggle_left.gif" />
</a>
```